# What is the right way to blend C++ and Blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I recently switch to using unreal engine from unity. I have had some experience with C++, but none with Blueprint. Obviously, I wanted to do everything in C++ but I have read online that it is probably better to use both. Right now I am confused on how to blend these 2. I have thought of two ways:
1. Use Blueprint to declare classes, and then use C++ to write components that handle logic (similar to MonoBehavior in Unity) that will be added to blueprint classes.
2. The class, with all its components and variables are written in C++, and then Blueprint will inherit from that class. Blueprint can be used to change instance variables' values quickly.

Are either of those ways good? Are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use both methods in a way. So I would define each actor in C++ and have BP inherit from it. But I also use components written in C++ inherited in BP which I add them to the BP actor classes.

Actors are the actual objects you see and use in game, and components are to share logic between the actors without having to inherit from each other when they do not have anything in common in the game world.

Comment: Do you create a BP class for each C++ actor in your project? In other words, if you have ten C++ actors, you will create ten BP classes. Why is have a BP class for each C++ actor class useful? I've been reading Unreal tutorials and they do it for each C++ (actor, GameMode, etc.) class and I don't understand why they do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I did it for all actors. As for why, it is because basically anything not related to the actors logic in regards to visual fx or audio is done in BP. This is easier to change and also for other people who are not into C++. All the other logic is done in C++ in my case.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes sense to me. But I don't do it and I can change, for example, the static mesh for a UStaticMeshComponent declared with UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Components"). So, I don't really understand why I have to create a BP class for each C++ class. Thanks again for your comment.